# Spring boot can't invoke Service because Service is null exception

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, autowired

**This is Exception:** enter code herejava.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.company.MedicalManagement.repository.DoctorRepository.findById(Object)" because "this.doctorRepository" is null

**And this class:**

```
    package com.company.MedicalManagement.dtoConverter;
    
    import com.company.MedicalManagement.dto.DoctorDTO;
    import com.company.MedicalManagement.dto.PatientDTO;
    import com.company.MedicalManagement.dto.RequestPatient;
    import com.company.MedicalManagement.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
    import com.company.MedicalManagement.model.Patient;
    import com.company.MedicalManagement.service.DoctorService;
    import com.company.MedicalManagement.service.PatientService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    import java.util.Optional;
    import java.util.function.Function;
    
    @Component
    public class RequestPatientConverter implements Function<RequestPatient, Patient> {

        private DoctorService doctorService;
```

//Error doctorService is null, this point`

```
        @Autowired
        public RequestPatientConverter(DoctorService doctorService) {
            this.doctorService = doctorService;
        }
    
        public RequestPatientConverter() {
        }
    
        @Override
        public Patient apply(RequestPatient requestPatient) {
            Patient patient = new Patient();
            patient.setId(requestPatient.getId());
            patient.setPatientBirthdate(requestPatient.getBirthdate());
            patient.setFullName(requestPatient.getFullname());
            Optional<DoctorDTO> optionalDoctorDTO = doctorService.findById(requestPatient.getDoctorId());
            if (optionalDoctorDTO.isPresent()){
                patient.setDoctor(new DtoDoctorConverter().apply(optionalDoctorDTO.get()));
            }
    
            return patient;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add @Service on DoctorService class.
And make final it.
private final DoctorService doctorService;
And test it again.

Comment: @MohammadJavad thanks for attention, but I just change sturcture